# Linux,How to show absolute path in shell promt?

Tags: linux, centos

now my shell shows a short path like this

[image]

I want to show full absolute path in the front.Like this

[image]

How to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the `PS1` variable with `\w` and store it in your e.g `.bash_profile`

An example

`export PS1="\u@\h \w> "`

Where

`\u` – Username

`\h` – Hostname

`\w` – Current working directory, full path (ie: /data/temp)

Check out following [tutorial](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/04/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail.html) for more options.

Comment: How to refresh to make it work after modified the .bash_profile

Comment: restart your `bash` instance, or initiate a new one, just by entering `bash` command

Comment: Or source your `.bash_profile` by using `. ./.bash_profile`.Saves logging in and out everytime you make a change.